# How to lazy load jquery for Angular app , In order to reduce first request size?

Tags: jquery, angular, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I am building an angular app .In one of its  module ( a component of it : We need to use existing written jquery code ) . I am thinking of loading it lazily ? Is that possible ?

Comment: What you tried so far, And using `jquery` in angular is a bad practice you have to avoid that if possible.

Comment: As I already mentioned it's an existing code . I know it's bad practice but since we need to add so I am bound to add !

Comment: If you're using jQuery in Angular then reducing first request size isn't your primary concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it is normally not needed, everything you do with jQuery in that template you could do with js/ts in your angular component code...
But if you have to use jQuery for some reason just load it in that component code (on init or after view init) in which you need it.
So it will get lazy loaded when that component is called... Do not put it in app component!

Comment: Here is an example how you can load scripts in component code, but there are many different ways to do so... http://blog.davidjs.com/2018/09/insert-script-tags-in-angular-components/

Comment: Thanks ToTaTaRi for the answer !! We are going with hard deadline so that's why doing it for now . I am also not in favour of using jQuery with Angular app